# How can i hooking with seccomp?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, hook, seccomp

I'm looking for a way to perform Hooking with seccomp or seccomp-bpf.

I want to set a rule so that when a syscall is performed (eg read) I can change the process or the answer that comes back from Syscall.
And I must use seccomp.

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to modify the `struct seccomp_data`, however, this is a read-only struct.

To bypass this restriction you can use BPF jointly with `ptrace`, filter syscalls with BPF and modify them using `ptrace`.